# Directory not found jupyterlab

Tags: jupyter-lab

I get this popup/error (run this in windows):

```
Directory not found: ""
```

See also:

[image]

I click dismiss and everything appears to work fine otherwise. It there anything I can do to fix this little annoyance (google did not reveal much)? Thanks!

PS:

Not sure if these help?:

```
[I 2022-01-04 12:16:28.092 ServerApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
[C 2022-01-04 12:16:28.176 ServerApp]

    To access the server, open this file in a browser:
        file:///C:/Users/xyz/AppData/Roaming/jupyter/runtime/jpserver-11040-open.html
    Or copy and paste one of these URLs:
        http://localhost:8888/lab?token=6b9b007867431c17eb43b8a7246e068c82ebd4a2b79911d1
     or http://127.0.0.1:8888/lab?token=6b9b007867431c17eb43b8a7246e068c82ebd4a2b79911d1
[W 2022-01-04 12:16:33.069 ServerApp] 404 GET /api/contents/C%3A/Repos?content=1&1641298593065 (::1): No such file or directory: C:/Repos
[W 2022-01-04 12:16:33.070 ServerApp] No such file or directory: C:/Repos
[W 2022-01-04 12:16:33.072 ServerApp] 404 GET /api/contents/C%3A/Repos?content=1&1641298593065 (::1) 4.29ms referer=http://localhost:8888/lab
[I 2022-01-04 12:16:34.302 LabApp] Build is up to date
```

Comment: There should be logs in the web developer console and/or in the jupyter server logs. Hard to tell anything without those.

Comment: @krassowski thanks - I added some outputs in PS:

Comment: https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/12111